# how to send QImages via gstreamer over udp

Tags: qt, gstreamer, qimage

I am using non supported v4L camera and i need to stream video to remote Pc using gstreamer.
I have successfully stream it on host computer using Qt and QImages .
earlier I have asked question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33943704/place-external-live-video-frames-from-non-supported-v4l-file-into-gstreamer-qt)

about how to feed external frames into gstreamer .
I read blog [here](http://amarghosh.blogspot.co.uk/2012/01/gstreamer-appsrc-in-action.html) and tried to implement it  using gstreamer 1.0 but somehow its not working as expected.
So I thought of streaming qimages via gstreamer in same network but on different workstation. I am wondering if someone can give me starting point of how to send Qimages using gstreamer 1.0. I am not asking for code but just a direction.
 I am very new to this multi-media stuff so I will be grateful if you explain it in layman's language.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to determine what protocol and encoding type you want to use to transmit it over UDP.  I'd recommend h264 over RTP for most cases.

GStreamer offers a wide collection of plugins to do this, including a command line utility called gst-launch.  Here are some basic send/receive commands:

`gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc pattern=ball ! video/x-raw,width=1280,height=720 ! videoconvert ! x264enc ! h264parse ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=localhost port=7777`

`gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=7777 ! rtpbin ! rtph264depay ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! autovideosink`

When you write applications that use a GStreamer pipeline, the simplest way to get frames to that pipeline is with an `appsrc`.  So you might have something like this:

```
const char* pipeline = "appsrc name=mysrc caps=video/x-raw,width=1280,height=720,format=RGB ! videoconvert ! x264enc ! h264parse ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=localhost port=7777";

GError* error(NULL);
GstElement* bin = gst_parse_bin_from_description(tail_pipe_s.c_str(), true, &error);
if(bin == NULL || error != NULL) {
        ...
}

GstElement* appsrc = gst_bin_get_by_name(GST_BIN(bin), "mysrc");

GstAppSrcCallbacks* appsrc_callbacks = (GstAppSrcCallbacks*)malloc(sizeof(GstAppSrcCallbacks));
memset(appsrc_callbacks, 0, sizeof(GstAppSrcCallbacks));
appsrc_callbacks->need_data = need_buffers;
appsrc_callbacks->enough_data = enough_buffers;
gst_app_src_set_callbacks(GST_APP_SRC(appsrc), appsrc_callbacks, (gpointer)your_data, free);

gst_object_unref(appsrc);
```

Then in a background thread you make calls to `gst_app_src_push_buffer`, which would involve reading the raw data from your QImage and converting it to a GstBuffer.

OR

Maybe QT has some easier way that I'm not aware of.  :)